# Acessar servidor Debian pelo IP externamente

Tags: apache, linux

Liberei em meu Apache 2 a porta 8080 para que possa ser acessado externamente, consigo acessar assim:

```
http://meu_ip:8080/nome_de_uma_pasta
```

Seria possível acessar o servidor apenas com **Meu IP**? Sem colocar **:8080**

assim

```
http://meu_ip/nome_de_uma_pasta
```

Comment: Criando um [dns dinamico](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_dinâmico), talvez. Ou configurando para a porta 80.

Comment: Você pode tentar um redirecionamento de porta no seu gateway

Comment: @WictorChaves como eu faria isso? No admin do meu modem?

Comment: Eu posso te passar a ideia, mas te fala onde ir é complicado, porque cada modem/roteador é de uma forma, mas funciona assim, tudo que chega na porta 80 será direcionado para porta 8080

Comment: Pesquisa o modelo do seu roteador "como fazer redirecionamento de portas com o roteador xpto02", o procedimento é simples, em geral há dois campos você colocar a porta de origem e de destino 80 -> 8080.

Comment: Isso é um IP fixo ou é o IP que teu provedor alocou para você momentaneamente?

Comment: @MagicHat contratei IP Fixo

Comment: Como está o arquivo `ports.conf`?

Comment: Listen 80
Listen 8080

<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

Answer (score 2):

Configura um VirualHost no seu apache apontando para a porta que deseja.
Exemplo:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
        ServerName servico.mydomain.com
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / http://servico.mydomain.com:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://servico.mydomain.com:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

Poderá fazer o mesmo caso deseje utilizar outras portas, ou seja, vários VirtualHost.

```
<VirtualHost *:9090>
        ServerName outroservico.mydomain.com
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / http://outroservico.mydomain.com:9090/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://outroservico.mydomain.com:9090/
</VirtualHost>
```